# Execute Command with xterm and close

Tags: linux, bash, xterm, linux-terminal

Im trying to execute a program with xterm and then close xterm with program running but it seems this doesn't work like I would expect it.

In bash there is the option `bash -c [command]` is there something in xterm too? Currently im using `xterm -e [command]` but this keeps the xterm window open till' my program has finished. But I want to open it, run the program, close it and keep the program running.

Why i want have a program startet through xterm when im not even using it?
Im calling this through xpra on another computer but its not possible to only launch the program because i need it with the environment on the other pc.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That looked good for the first try even if it seemed like it just got my open windown on the one machine to tho other and didnt open a new one. But now i cat get it to work anymore with nohup. What is the exact syntax? I tried `xterm -e 'nohup sleep 5000 /path/to/program'` But then i only try `xterm -e '/path/to/program'` it works again with the unwanted xterm window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think You need `xpra`. `ssh` is a good choice

```
ssh user@hostname /path/to/program
```

or `ssh` + `screen`

```
ssh user@hostname "screen /path/to/program"
```

or `xpra` + `screen`

```
xpra user@hostname "screen /path/to/program"
```

Comment: That doesnt help me unfortunately, im bound to xpra.

Comment: @Nico `xpra`+`screen` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about how things work.  You don't need a terminal to run a program.

"Start `xterm` so you can start a process and then exit `xterm`" reduces to "start a process" and you can factor out `xterm` entirely.

I'm guessing you are looking for

```
nohup command >command.out 2>command.err &
```

which starts `command` as a background process (because of the `&`) with output going to `command.out` and error messages to `command.err`.

If you don't care about output or the signal handling with `nohup`, you might simply just want

```
command &
```

This doesn't allow you to interact with the background command (but neither does closing the `xterm` so I guess you don't need that); if you want to be able to do that, consider `screen` or `tmux` which lets you run the program in a virtual terminal you can disconnect from and reconnect to later.

Comment: Yes, i need the terminal. I'm connecting to another Pc via xpra and call a program but this program need to be run in a terminal

Comment: Then from where are you running `xterm` and why can't you run `xpra` from there?

Comment: Im on a laptop in my network from there i run xpra onto another workstation in my network. On this workstation i run this program and view it via xpra on this laptop, but the program need to be started with xterm but i dont want to see this xterm window.

Comment: There are no programs which need to be started with `xterm`.  I'm imagining you have been told you need to `xpra somewhere xterm something` to run `something` on `somewhere` but that's generally speaking not true.  The answer you already received with `ssh somewhere something &` is correct and exhaustive, and if it doesn't work for you then your question lacks several crucial details.

Comment: The program is selfwritten and it need to get started via xterm. My question is noch lacking crucial details you just wont accept that your answer doesn't help me. Im glad this forum exists an i got many good tips already but why are there some guys not accepting my requirements?

Comment: I want to start a a xterm via xpra and in this xterm i need to start a program and then i want xterm to be closed but the program needs to stay alive.

Comment: Maybe its ok to move this terminal where it doesn't show up. That should work too but i dont want to see it

Comment: You keep saying that, and I keep saying that cannot be exactly true.

Comment: What is "not true"? That i have this requirement? I dont want solutions for a problem i dont have. I WANT to start a program with xpra through xterm and then make xterm "invisible" however...

Comment: You keep saying you are *required* to use `xterm` to start this program and I'm telling you that this does not make sense. Either the program requires a graphical user interface (which `xterm` does not provide, though if you are able to start `xterm` you will also be able to run other graphical clients) or it does not (in which case it doesn't matter which terminal or other console is used to launch the program, and so `xterm` isn't necessary either, and `ssh` or similar should suffice).